# How do I Convert a String to a System.Uri?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im building an app in visual studio (Visual Basic or C#) for my [website](http://www.edgface.webstarts.com/). (This is not a website advertisement)

there are 2 versions of the website. An old one and a New one. In the settings area of the app, a user presses a button which changes a variable (or setting). So when that button is clicked, the user can then go to the webbrowser and be greeted with that choice of the old one or the new one as they selected.

But when I code it in the browser form with `webbrowser1.url = my.settings.website` it throws back an error with a blue ~ line under `my.settings.website` saying: `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.uri'`.

Does anyone know a way round this?

Comment: You don't need a way around it. You need to read the message. You need a way to convert a string to a `System.Uri`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`webbrowser1.Url` property expects an object of type `System.Uri` and you are supplying just a `String`, which can't be converted automatically. Try the following:

```
webbrowser1.Url = new System.Uri(my.settings.website);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
webbrowser1.url = new System.uri(my.settings.website) ;
```